# How is $E[c(X)|X] = c(X)$ derived?

Tags: conditional-expectation

I understand that this is a property of conditional expectation, but I am not too clear on how it is derived.

Comment: Let $X$ take value $x$. The mathematical expectation is by definition: $\mathbb{E}[c(X)|X=x] = \sum_y c(y) P(X=y|X=x)$. $P(X=y|X=x)$ is 1 if $x=y$ and zero otherwise. And this is valid for all possible values of $X$.

Comment: Well, that is as simple as "what is mean of $c(X)$ when $X=x$?" the answer is $c(x)$ (small letter $x$ here)

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431422/how-can-i-show-that-the-conditional-expectation-ex-mid-x-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will complement the technical answer with an intuitive one. $E[c(X)|X]$ means expected value of $c(X)$ (a function of a random variable $X$) given $X$ (that is, given a particular value of $X$ has been observed). Since $X$ has been observed, so has $c(X)$, and its expected value is just its observed value. Therefore, $E[c(X)|X]=c(X)$

Answer (score 2):

To understand the "derivation" of this rule, you need to look at [the formal definition of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2), which is actually defined directly by its integral equation (see similar answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365440/365441#365441)).  The rule in your question is a trivial consequence of the definition.   Given some measureable function $c:\mathscr{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a valid conditional expectation $g(X) \equiv \mathbb{E}(c(X)|X)$ is *any* measureable function $g:\mathscr{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the equation:

$$\int \limits_\mathscr{X} g(x) \ dF_X(x) = \int \limits_\mathscr{X} c(x) \ dF_X(x).$$

Any measureable function $g$ that satisfies this equation is considered to be a valid conditional expectation.  Clearly, the function $g=c$ satisfies this equation, so we can say that:

$$c(X) = g(X) = \mathbb{E}(c(X)|X).$$

This rule says that we can "take out what is known"; it is a trivial consequence of the underlying definition of conditional probability.  (There may be other valid conditional expectations, but they will all be equivalent to this one, except on a set with probability zero.  For this reason, we tend to think of $c(X)$ as "the" conditional expectation in this case.  This is a reasonable shorthand for the more formally correct statement.)

Comment: Doesn't it miss one condition: Measureable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the condition, that is $\sigma(X)$?

Comment: While I might be mistaken, I think that's what it would mean for a function on $\mathscr{X}$ to be measureable (i.e., measureable with respect to the sigma-field on its own domain).  In any case, these kinds of questions tend to be asked by people who are not familiar with measure theory, so I prefer to gloss over the measureability conditions a bit.

Comment: Well, but the natural $\sigma$-algebta on $\mathscr{X}$ and the (sub) $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variable $X$ is not the same thing! I don't think it makes sense to avoid measurability in this case.

Comment: Kinda.  In practice, the mere fact that the function $c$ is being used in the analysis means that it must be a measureable function (or the premise of the question is invalid).  Since $g=c$ is a valid conditional expectation, the latter is therefore measureable by implication.